# add insert,retrieve,update and delete in one php form

Tags: php, forms

How to add insert, retrieve, update and delete in one php form?
My form's page name is registration1.php and if i want to insert then

```
action=registration.php
```

But if i want 4 button together then how can i?

Answer (score 3):

Simply add 4 submit buttons to your form, in your PHP code, check which one was pressed.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text" value="testing" />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="log in" />
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
<input type="submit" name="update" value="time to update" />
```

Clicking on a button will result in a $_POST array that looks like

```
Array ( [text] => testing [update] => time to update ) // clicked update button, see no loging or delete buttons.
```